# no image on home page of magento sample data

Tags: magento-1.9

I managed to install magento with sample data with "all set" message, when i tried to open the sample data on localhost it does not display images on home page only

Please find `http://postimg.org/image/tr3k0rpjl/` (image here)

On rest of the pages, images are coming correctly..

Any kind of attention to this question will be highly appreciable.

Thankyou

Comment: What is your homepage code? You can find it in the CMS Pages section in the admin.